# I want to perfrom CRUD operation from one salesforce org to another salesforce org using REST API. can anyone help me out?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have Consumer Key, Consumer Secret.
what to use in call back url.
is OAuth2.0 authorizaton is needed ? how to perform overall operation.

Comment: have you already tried something ?

Comment: [REST Client Salesforce to Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/rest-client-salesforce-to-salesforce)
[Apex code for REST](https://gist.github.com/noeticpenguin/7083556)
i have these 2 links as a resource. i have already try connecting a java app to sf org using REST API.

Comment: [apex code for REST client](https://gist.github.com/noeticpenguin/7083556) i am unable to understand this code.

Comment: Have you read this doc: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf

Comment: i have read alrady, but in this doc, nothing like sf org to org connection.